# Use Old SKTextureAtlas or SpriteAtlas

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I made a game that makes use of many textureAtlases. I am currently using SpriteAtlases in the assets.xcassets folder which works great until testing devices below iOS 10.

Running on any devices at iOS 9 displays this issue below and it won't load the textures.

```
-[CUIThemeRendition newImageFromCSIDataSlice:ofBitmap: usingColorspace:] Unsupported pixel format in CSI got 5

Unable to create unsliced image from csi bitmap data.
```

I couldn't fix this issue (I read that it might be a bug) so my only two options I can think of is to either use the old .atlases in the project bundle or only have my game support iOS 10.0 and newer when using the spriteAtlases. Which is the better option or is there another alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the .atlas method is old and inefficient. The XCassets .spriteatlas is, by far, a better usage of memory and will make your project run better.

*My* recommendation would be to not support iOS 9 and lower. Users still on iOS 9 are such a small minority, you would be screwing your iOS 10 users by using this inefficient method. At this point, most people have upgraded to iOS 10 or newer or bought a new device.

It gets to a point where us developers physically cannot continue to support older iOS versions. In fact, if I remember correctly, Twitter just recently [dropped support for iOS 9](https://techcrunch.com/2018/08/23/twitter-ends-support-for-ios-9-and-lower/). I think it would be a good idea to follow suit.